# Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in android 12

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have try to install my app on android 12, then i have shown this error:

```
Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1552365075.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #227): com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicitvalue for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
```

So, How can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `android:exported` for your receiver in manifest. You can read about it [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)